# MethodNotAllowedHttpException Error

Tags: php, laravel-4

With following code, I am getting `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` error. The code is for simple blog post. When i click on the following link, i get the error.

```
   HTML::link('admin/createpost', 'Add Post')
```

I could not find what is wrong with the code. please help me out. Thanks

Route.php:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');
Route::get('login', 'HomeController@getLogin');
Route::post('login', 'HomeController@postLogin');
Route::get('logout', 'HomeController@logout');
Route::get('users', 'HomeController@showusers');


Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){

Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@getIndex');
Route::get('admin/createpost', array('as'=>'createpost' ,'uses'=>'AdminController@getCreate'));
Route::post('admin/createpost', array('as'=>'createpost','uses'=>'AdminController@postCreate'));

});
```

AdminConroller:

```
<?php

class AdminController extends \BaseController {

    protected $table ='posts';
    protected $post;

    public function getIndex()
    {

        return View::make('admin.index');

    }


    public function getCreate()
    {
        return View::make('admin.createpost');

    }


    public function postCreate()
    {
        // Declare the rules for the form validation
       $rules = array(
            'title'   => 'required|min:3',
            'content' => 'required|min:3'
        );

        // Validate the inputs
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        // Check if the form validates with success
        if ($validator->passes())
        {
            // Create a new blog post
            $user = Auth::user();
            $post = new Post();

            // Update the blog post data
            $post->title            = Input::get('title');
            $post->content          = Input::get('content');
            $post->username          = $user->username;

            // Was the blog post created?
            if($post->save())
            {
                // Redirect to the new blog post page
             return Redirect::to('admin/createpost');

            }

            // Redirect to the blog post create page
           return Redirect::to('admin/createpost');


        }


      return View::make('admin.createpost')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant test this - but I think it is because you cant use the same link and the same name, unless you use Named Routes.

Try changing your route names to this which is the normal restful standard

```
Route::get('admin/createpost', array('as'=>'createpost' ,'uses'=>'AdminController@getCreate'));
Route::post('admin', array('as'=>'storepost','uses'=>'AdminController@postCreate'));
```

Then link to it with this

```
HTML::linkRoute('admin.createpost', 'Add Post')
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation.  If i change the routes to `Route::get('admin/createpost', array('as'=>'createpost' ,'uses'=>'AdminController@getCreate'));` `Route::post('admin/createpost', 'AdminController@postCreate');`
It works fine with no error. I observed in sample codes for post routes no named routing is used. Should it be strictly followed?

Comment: I strictly follow it. As your application grows, it becomes significant more powerful routing to be able to target exactly what you want. And I tend to get less errors and strange routing issues (like this one) when I used named routes.

Comment: How the laravel assumes post route corresponds get route if links are different. Do u mean Route names must be different.

Comment: Yes - route names must be 'unique' for every single route.